# Select element only if a later sibling exists

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, conditional-formatting

In my HTML structure, I have it set up like this:

```
<body>
   <main>
      <section>
      ...
      </section>

      <aside>
      ...
      </aside>
   </main>
</body>
```

The problem is, not all pages have `<aside>`

I need to select `<section>` and give it a `max-width: 500px;` **ONLY when `<aside>` is present**. The default is `section { max-width: 1000px; }` (when `<aside>` is absent)

Unlike in [Selector for one tag directly followed by another tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132366/selector-for-one-tag-directly-followed-by-another-tag;) the user [asking the question] wants to style "B" ALL the time. Also, in this question, the user wants to select "B" (not "A")

---

- I need to style `<section>` ONLY if `<aside>` is present.
- I can't change the order of the HTML >_<
- Can it be done with CSS only?
- What selector do I need or how to set it up?
- If it can't be done with CSS (I rather it be CSS-only), how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can it be done with CSS only? --- unfortunately not

Comment: You are essentially asking for a previous sibling selector in css which don't exist. Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126531/css-selector-if-exist-adjacent-sibling

Comment: Believe it or not, "whatever I want it to be" used to be the same as you - including the prefix in the title. But the [community has collectively agreed that that sort of thing doesn't belong](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) - so 1) there *is* a need to remove it 2) and it's not what *I* want it to be, it's what community policy wants. I won't edit your question again, but I can't guarantee that anybody else who comes along won't re-edit it either.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

### **A neat little trick**

You can achieve what you want by using a trick to check ***if the `<section>` element is the only element in `<main>`.*** This will not work, if there are any other elements there. In your case it should work like this (http://jsfiddle.net/Ljm323qb/2/):

```
section {
     max-width: 500px;
}
/* The STAR of the show */
section:only-child {
     max-width: 1000px;
}
```

As illustrated in this codepen: http://codepen.io/omarjuvera/pen/ByXGyK?editors=110

---

### **General stuff on Sibling Selectors**

There's the `+` selector which would select a sibling that comes right after the element (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

And there's the `~` selector which selects all following siblings (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

You could achieve it by putting the `<aside>` element before the `<section>` element and using a sibling selector.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ljm323qb/1/

**A quick look in the future**
Soon this will be possible, with a new `:has` pseudo class (http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#relational)
You'll be able to call something like `main:has(> aside) > section { ... }` but we'll have to wait for that, unfortunately :(

Comment: I can't change the order >_<

Comment: Hmm how about this: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#only-child-pseudo will work starting at IE9... https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/o/only-child/

Comment: It relays on the fact, that the `<section>` element is the only element in the `<main>`

Comment: @wsws it works. Edit your answer as a solution, with a jsFiddle =)

Comment: @Omar Done. I still let the general explanation for siblings there and added a method, that will work some time in the future, but is not implemented yet.

Comment: `:only-child` is not new to Selectors 4, so it's not exactly surprising that it works in IE9 - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#only-child-pseudo

Comment: Also a shorter way to write the selector using `:has()` is `section:has(+ aside)`.

Comment: A little bit more general hack would be :nth-last-child(1). It allows section to have previous siblings ( not limited to being the only child). But has less support

Comment: @vals: Other than one or two versions of Chrome that have bugs, support for :only-child and :nth-last-child() is identical. And neither of these are hacks - unless you consider using structural pseudo-classes a hack.

Comment: @BoltClock   I said hack meaning that we are not checking if aside is present or not, but we are checking another condition that is more or less related to it.

Answer (score 5):

### WITHOUT JAVASCRIPT

#### If you can change the order of your html elements to:

```
<body>
   <main>
      <aside>
      ...
      </aside>

      <section>
      ...
      </section>
   </main>
</body>
```

#### You can do it like this by using a sibling selector:

```
aside ~ section {
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Correct and very good support up to IE7.
Also good approach to use ~ and not + because this way the elements don't need to be next to each others. +1

Comment: This solution would work, if he could change the DOM. Unfortunately he wrote: `I can't change the order of the HTML >_<` so I guess, that won't work.

Comment: You say "CSS ONLY", but then you go on to say "change the order of your html elements". That makes no sense.

Comment: I meant that this solution does not require javascript, I can understand that the heading is not 100% correct but I was speaking to the fact that the OP really did not want to use Javascript and needed a CSS only solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can toggle a class `.haveSidebar` to the **body** tag using **jQuery** and make your **CSS** for the `section` tag depends whether this class exists on the **body** tag or not:

**HTML**

```
<main>
    <section>
    </section>

    <aside>
    </aside>
</main>
```

**CSS**

```
main {
    width:100%;
}
main aside {
    width:300px;
    background:red;
    min-height:300px;
    float:left;
}
main section {
    width:100%;
    background:green;
    min-height:300px;
    float:left;
}
body.haveSidebar main section {
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
}
```

**JS**

```
var sideBar = $('body > main > aside');
if (sideBar.length > 0) {
    $('body').addClass('haveSidebar');
} else {
    $('body').removeClass('haveSidebar');
}
```

[Fiddle with aside tag](http://jsfiddle.net/x2tgxqod/2/)

[Fiddle without aside tag](http://jsfiddle.net/x2tgxqod/3/)

**Update**

Solution without `calc()`, by using `margin-left` property

```
main aside {
    width:300px;
    background:red;
    min-height:300px;
    position:relative;
}
main section {
    width:100%;
    background:green;
    min-height:300px;
    float:left;
}
.haveSidebar main section {
    margin-left:301px;
}
```

[Fiddle without calc()](http://jsfiddle.net/jhkqctrz/)

Comment: Is it save to use `calc()`? I love it, but since it's only a Candidate Recommendation, I wonder if we should use it yet... (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Specifications)

Comment: There's some people using it, but there is no guarantees of compatibility and it still buggy in some browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with the [:has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) selector, as follows:

```
:has(main aside) {
  section {
    max-width: 500px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's not the neatest way of doing things, you can run on document ready javascript function, to check if aside tag exists, and inject an in-line css to the section tag accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It would be fairly straightforward to accomplish this with JavaScript.

For example this will work:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        if (document.getElementsByTagName('aside')[0]) {
           document.getElementsByTagName('section')[0].style.max-width = '500px';
        } else {
            document.getElementsByTagName('section')[0].style.max-width = '1000px';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the possibility to put your aside element before the section one, you can use the [adjacent sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

```
aside + section{ max-width: 500px }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i believe it can only be done with some javascript.

```
if ($('main').find('aside').length>0)
{
    $('main').find('section').addClass('specificSection');
}
```

Comment: Is this JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: jquery which is a javasript library