# CSS Select Element with Sibling

Tags: html, css

I want to select an element if and only if its adjacent sibling is a certain element.

```
<div>
    <h1>Select Me</h1>
    <h2>I'm the sibling, yay!</h2>
    <div>
        <p>A paragraph.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <h1>Don't Select Me - I have no h2 sibling. :(</h1>
    <div>
        <p>A longer paragraph.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this particular example, I only want to select the first `h1` because it has an adjacent `h2`. The other `h1` doesn't meet that criteria so I don't want it selected.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29662009/css-select-element-only-if-a-later-sibling-exists) but it won't work for me because the element has other siblings and is never an only child.

Comment: You can't do this with current CSS selectors, as the `h1` appears before the `h2` and adjacent selectors only select elements after, not before.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara so I'm only left with using a class then?

Comment: Unless there are some other criteria you can select on, yes.

Comment: In the current spec, you cannot select a *previous* sibling selector. In the future you would be able to use the CSS `:has` expression, but for now stick to a class or JavaScript solution.

Comment: Okay, thanks guys!

Comment: Does <h1> always appear first in its parent element? You might be able to use :first-child, but that's kind of a big assumption on my part.

Comment: @Taconut Well that wouldn't really work because it doesn't take into account what the sibling is.

Answer (score 1):

There is no previous element selector in CSS yet. There is a adjacent sibling selector: `+` and there is a general sibling selector: `~`.

**Thought I can give you a jQuery solution:**

```js
$('h2').prev('h1').addClass('favH1');
```

```css
h1.favH1{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <h1>Select Me</h1>
    <h2>I'm the sibling, yay!</h2>
    <div>
        <p>A paragraph.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <h1>Don't Select Me - I have no h2 sibling. :(</h1>
    <div>
        <p>A longer paragraph.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would make it more specific, like this: `$('h2').prev('h1').addClass('favH1');` otherwise any other element that might be behind any `h2` tag will get that styling...

Comment: @Aziz thanks! Updated the code!

Comment: I'm upvoting but I can't really accept the answer as the question is with regards to CSS. This works though. Putting a class before the page was rendered was an easier solution for me. Thanks anyway!